# Convert structure array to matrix

Tags: matlab

I am trying to convert a structure array to a matrix. Each field of the structure stores a vector that can reach up to 520000 rows. There can be up to 20 fields in a single structure array, but number of rows is the same across the fields.

As a down scaled example consider the structure `s`, where each field is an integer:

```
s=struct('a',1,'b',2);
s(2)=struct('a',3,'b',4);
s=s';
```

In the desired output, each field will correspond to a column. `a` values will be in the first column, while `b` values will be in the second:

```
desiredOutput = [1 2; 3 4];
```

I have approached this in an indirect way:

```
cell2mat(struct2cell(s))'
```

However, this involves two transformations which i find unnecessary due to the well behaved nature of my structure.

I have also approached this using a for loop:

```
fields = fieldnames(s);
nrows = size(s,1);
ncols = numel(fields);
desiredOutput = nan(nrows,ncols);
for jj=1:ncols
    desiredOutput(:,jj) = [s.(fields{fields(jj)})]';
end
```

I hoped to find a `struct2mat` function but it does not exist. Is there a simpler way to accomplish this task that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar to this written out. So, if you don't mind, I will 'kinda' copy that out over here.

```
data(1,1).val = 1; 
data(1,2).val = 2; 
data(2,1).val = 3; 
data(2,2).val = 4;
```

This gives a `2x2 struct` with field `val`.

```
A = reshape([data.val],size(data))
```

Now, A looks like this `[ 1 2 : 3 4]`

```
A =
      1 2
      3 4
```

Does that help?

Comment: It is an interesting approach, but for a slightly different case. You must have identical fieldnames for this approach to work, while in my use case they are different, but thanks for sharing and giving it a try